# How to save game progress with Processing

Tags: processing

Im making a small game through Processing and I am wondering how to make the game being able to save game progress. I googled the topic and found stuff like saveString(), and serialization but I don't really get it nor understand how to use it.
Basically I need a feature where when the player click save, all the current variables in its current state, along with the whole program, will be saved. They can later reopen the data and continue the game from where they left off.
Was wondering if you guys know any tutorials or maybe give me some tip what to look at.

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this. Google "java write to file" for a ton of tutorials. You might also check out the saveStrings() and loadStrings() functions in the Processing API if you want to stick with Processing.

Comment: is there a way to save variables and load variables in Processsing?

Comment: I just gave you two approaches. What happened when you tried them?

Comment: I tried to save a variable that is changing base on frameCount,but it only gave me an error. 

`int a =0; void setup(){ size(400,400); } void draw(){ a=frameCount; String [] d = split(a,''); saveStrings("text.txt",d); }`

The error says "badly formed character constant (expecting quote,got))

Comment: Yeah, that syntax doesn't make a lot of sense. The split() function takes a String and a char, but you're passing in an int. You have to pass in a String.

Comment: which is y im asking how do i save a variable that is an int.

Comment: Again, what you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. You already have an int variable. You need a String value instead. What are you trying to split on?

Comment: Still, it'd work, if only you took the trouble of calling `split(a.toString(),'');`
I recommend diving into a few books on Java, Nelson :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to loadStrings(),saveStrings() you could also consider using a [JSON object](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html) and similar functions like [saveJSONObject()](https://processing.org/reference/saveJSONObject_.html) and [loadJSONObject()](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html). The advantage over using Strings is it would simplify serialising primitive types and nested structures.

Here's a very basic fictional example:

```
{
    "level":1,
    "difficulty":0,
    "checkpoint":3,
    "paused":true,
    "items":[0,1,2]
}
```

This what how you'd load/parse it, then modify and save it in Processing (if the above is saved as state.json):

```
JSONObject state;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  //load JSON
  state = loadJSONObject("state.json");
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  text(state.toString(),10,15);
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'd'){
    //access JSON (using get methods) and modify (using set methods)
    state.setInt("difficulty",state.getInt("difficulty") + 1);
  }
  //save JSON
  saveJSONObject(state,"state.json");
}
```

Notice in the example an integer is get and set using [getInt()](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_getInt_.html) and [setInt()](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_setInt_.html). Be sure to checkout the reference and examples. There are similar methods for booleans/strings/floats as well as nested JSON objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [saveStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html) and the [loadStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) function.  First you need to make a text file(.txt) in the data folder. Than, you can use something like this,

```
//Saving

String words = "apple bear cat dog";
String[] list = split(words, ' ');//This creates a list with apple, bear, cat, and dog

// Writes the strings to a file, each on a separate line

saveStrings("nouns.txt", list);//This copies everything from the list named 'list' and pastes it onto the file 'nouns.txt'
//Calling upon the save
String lines[] = loadStrings("nouns.txt");]//This creates a list that has everything on the file 'nouns.txt'

//doing stuff with the save

println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
   println(lines[i]);//This is self explanatory very simple stuff
}
```